# How to prevent SQL injection in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I wrote a procedure in SQL Server like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].Filter
     (@select nvarchar(500) = 'select *',
      @query nvarchar(max) = '')
as
begin
    if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#prs1','U') is not null)
         drop table #prs1

    select * 
    into #prs1 
    from Table1

    declare @q nvarchar(max)
    set @q = @select + ' from #prs1 ' + @query;

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @q
end
```

I want to know how to prevent SQL injection in this scenario?

Why I am doing this: because I want to filter the result based on multiple tables and I don't want to get all data in memory.

Comment: With query parts like you proposed, good luck securing it. `@query` could be anything, like `WHERE 1=1; DROP DATABASE ....`. And yes filterning keywords won't help you either.

Comment: The very way you're doing is prevents you from securing this against SQL injection - passing in the list of columns to select, and the where conditions, is a classic case of an approach that will ultimately result in SQL injection attacks. The only way to prevent this is **not doing it** this way .

Comment: i wrote my query in Linq format it was very slow(entity framework). what am i suppose to do?

Comment: @Mashtani, create your first index?